# Cannot read data "objectname" of undefined angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Unable to read the data from parent scope to directive. Getting error like

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowCollection' of undefined

Can you please help me out of this.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1 as one">
   <ltcg-table options="one.rowCollection"></ltcg-table>     
</div>
```

**Grid HTML**

```
<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>birth date</th>
        <th>balance</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
        <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
        <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
        <td>{{row.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
(function () {

      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);

          function one() {
                       this.song="Murali";
                      // alert("gg");
                     this.rowCollection = [
                        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
                        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
                        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
                    ];
                      //alert($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].name);
                       //alert($scope.gridOptions);
             };




        myApp.directive('ltcgTable', function() {

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                scope: {
                    'options': '='
                },
                templateUrl: "ltcg-table.html",
                link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                        alert(scope.$parent.options.rowCollection);
                        scope.rowCollection = scope.options.rowCollection;
                }
              }             
        });

      myApp.controller('ctrl1', one)



})();
```

Comment: can you explain why you try `scope.$parent.options` in alert?

Answer (score 2):

So, you have a directive with isolated scope. In this case `scope` parameter in link function referes to this scope, in your case this next object

```
{
    'options': '='
}
```

So when you do in html `options="one.rowCollection"` value of *one.rowCollection* was binded to *options* property, so for access to it you should use `scope.options` in link function, on just *options* in view.

also `$parent` property set to parent scope, in your case - "ctrl1" controller scope. So you can directly go to controller and get what you want.

When use *controller as* syntax reference to controller saved in controller scope. So for access controller you should use it name.

Sample:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function one() {
  this.song = "Murali";
  // alert("gg");
  this.rowCollection = [{
    firstName: 'Laurent',
    lastName: 'Renard',
    birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'),
    balance: 102,
    email: 'whatever@gmail.com'
  }, {
    firstName: 'Blandine',
    lastName: 'Faivre',
    birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'),
    balance: -2323.22,
    email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'
  }, {
    firstName: 'Francoise',
    lastName: 'Frere',
    birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'),
    balance: 42343,
    email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'
  }];
  //alert($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].name);
  //alert($scope.gridOptions);
};

myApp.directive('ltcgTable', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      'options': '='
    },
    templateUrl: "ltcg-table.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      //go to controller directly
      scope.rowCollection = scope.$parent.one.rowCollection
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller('ctrl1', one)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1 as one">
    <ltcg-table options="one.rowCollection"></ltcg-table>
  </div>
  <script id="ltcg-table.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>first name</th>
          <th>last name</th>
          <th>birth date</th>
          <th>balance</th>
          <th>email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            Get data from scope.options
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in options">
          <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
          <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
          <td>{{row.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            <hr/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            Get data saved from controller directly in link function
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
          <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
          <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
          <td>{{row.email}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the above solution will work only when we set the specific controller object(one.rowCollection). But I want **dynamic** if I have multiple ctrls with different content  like        <div ng-controller="ctrl1 as one">
   <ltcg-table options="one.rowCollection"></ltcg-table>  
</div>
<div ng-controller="ctrl2 as two">
   <ltcg-table options="two.rowCollection"></ltcg-table>   
</div> then how to load different ctrls data in same directive.

Comment: @klmuralimohan, as you can see, in answer i provide **two** ways, and if you use first - all work fine. Look to first paragraph, and pay attention to html `<tr ng-repeat="row in options">`

Comment: @klmuralimohan, i'm a bit update answer, possibly now more clear

Comment: Yes, It is working fine. great solution Grundy. Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: @klmuralimohan, this possibly problem with `smart-table` module, as you can see, in snippet i not use it, because not know what is it :)

Answer (score 0):

You added `options` to your directive scope, so you can directly access it through`scope.options`. By the way, directives scopes are isolated (with the `scope: {}` notation), so you can't just go up and try to read parent scopes.

Comment: with isolated scope - `$parent` property also set. Not working just inheritance scope